# Is there a way in iOS to observe the home button being pushed?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am basically trying to make the device play a sound whenever the app exits (even if the phone is being turned off, the sound would play while the button is being held down). Is this possible?

Comment: Even if the phone is turned off, you want it to run code? Whut?

Comment: Sorry, I meant like in the process of being turned off, e.g. the user is holding down the bevel button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` UIApplicationDelegate method.

Alternately, you could listen for the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification notification.